# webEdition: How to copy language version from one language to another

Tags: php, internationalization

I have a webEdition project with multiple languages where someone filled french content into the (previous empty) swedish branch of the site. The pages are accessable with this kind of urls `exampledomain.de/subpath1/se/subpath2/placeholder.php` that have the `se` path in their path.
Within the backend the content is editable under the `se` language.

Now I want to make the french branch accessable via urls with an `fr`  part in the url like this.`exampledomain.de/subpath1/fr/subpath2/placeholder.php`.
Furthermore I would like to have the content editable under the `fr` language in the backend.

So basically I simply want to transform the swedish branch into a french branch. Does webEdition provide such kind of functionality?

I tried manually with globally replacing all `se`-substrings with `fr` in the database (a big operation with a huge regular expression to not accidently replace unwanted appearances of `se`) and renaming the appropriate document folder in the backend from `se` to `fr`. Then rebuilding the whole project.

This works in many ways as I have all the french urls with appropriate pages coming up and I have a french language within the content editor in the backend.

The big problem is that there are no contents. So I guess an appropriate relation in the database is not set. As my approach is a bit error-prone because it's impossible to check every replacement manually I would love to have webEdition handle this for me with a dedicated functionality.

So maybe anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I provide the answer myself. After correcting a typing error, the database operations worked fine so that I could solve my problem.

I figured out that the following twenty tables could be involved and therefore should be processed (Other tables were either empty or did contain user data that should not be modified):

we6_tblCategory, we6_tblConten, we6_tblexpor, we6_tblInde, we6_tblLin, we6_tblnavigation, we6_tblObjec, we6_tblObjectFiles (zwei Einträge in Path, we6_tblObject_1, we6_tblObject_2, we6_tblObject_3, we6_tblObject_4, we6_tblObject_5, we6_tblObject_6, we6_tblObject_7, we6_tblsearchtool, we6_tblTemplates, we6_tblTemporaryDoc, we6_tblversions, we6_tblWebAdmin

I replaced every occurrence of `sv-SE` with `fr-FR` and every `content__se` with `content__fr`.

Then I applied the following regular expression using preg_replace_callback in php

```
~('(se)\b|'(se)'|\b(se)'|_(se)\b|_(se)_|\b(se)_|/(se)\b|(?<!\.)\b(se)/|/(se)/|\"(se)\b|\b(se)\"|\"(se)\"|(?<=willbrandt)\.(se)\b)~si
```

This expression ensured that only wanted occurrences of 'se' would have been transformed to 'fr'. A little code in the callback ensured that the matches of the case-insensitive regular expression were replaced with the correct case (`se->fr`, `Se->Fr`, `SE->FR`).

After having processed the tables I imported them back to the webEdition's database and renamed the corresponding document folder from `se` to `fr` in the backend.

Things might be different in your project but at least the regular expression and the general process should work if you have a similar problem.